# Deploying Flask with Heroku

Tags: heroku, flask

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app to Heroku however upon pushing the code I get the error

```
2013-06-23T11:23:59.264600+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

I'm not sure what to try, I've tried changing the port from 5000 to 33507, but to no avail. My Procfile looks like this:

```
web: python main.py
```

`main.py` is the main Flask file which initiates the server.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your main.py (with any database credentials and whatnot removed)

Comment: Would you accept @msiemens post as the answer?

Answer (score 52):

In my Flask app hosted on Heroku, I use this code to start the server:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

When developing locally, this will use port 5000, in production Heroku will set the `PORT` environment variable.

(Side note: By default, Flask is only accessible from your own computer, not from any other in the network (see the [Quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/)). Setting `host='0.0.0.0'` will make Flask available from the network)

Answer (score 9):

In addition to [msiemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997063/msiemens)'s answer

```
import os
from run import app as application
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Your Procfile should specify the port address which in this case is stored in the heroku environment variable ${PORT}

`web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:${PORT} wsgi`

Answer (score 4):

Your `main.py` script cannot bind to a specific port, it needs to bind to the port number set in the `$PORT` environment variable. Heroku sets the port it wants in that variable prior to invoking your application.

The error you are getting suggests you are binding to a port that is not the one Heroku expects.

Answer (score 2):

This also fixes the problem of [H20: App boot timeout](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/45).

My Procfile looks like this:

```
web: gunicorn -t 150 -c gunicorn_config.py main:app --bind 0.0.0.0:${PORT}
```

and main.py:

```
port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```