# heroku error while "There's nothing here, yet."

Tags: python, docker, flask, heroku

I have deployed simple flask app on Heroku with Docker and access using heroku-simple-flask-prod.herokuapp.com. However, I get "There's nothing here, yet. Build something amazing" error page. As I know, this happens with incorrect DNS setting while using herokudns.com. But here I use herokuapp.com link. Which should be accessible in any case. So what is wrong here?

Flask code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "welcome to the flask tutorials"


if __name__ == "__main__":
        # below arrangment is done specially for Heroku
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260338/deploying-flask-with-heroku
        # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
        port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug = True)
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM    ubuntu:latest
RUN     apt-get update
RUN     apt-get install -y libxml2-dev xmlsec1
RUN     apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev
RUN     cd /usr/local/bin
RUN     ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python
RUN     pip3 --no-cache-dir install --upgrade pip
RUN     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY    . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN     pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD     python3 app.py
```

My heroku.yml

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
run:
  web: python3 app.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to me.

Use the Heroku CLI to [delete the app](https://help.heroku.com/LGKL6LTN/how-do-i-delete-destroy-a-heroku-application), then recreate it and push to heroku.